# multilingual php cms with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, get, multilingual

I am at prototype stage & working with `error_reporting(-1)`;. my blog will be in 2 languages. turkish + english.
my current plan is to show a very simple `index.php` to user to select his/her language. then send the page to `index2.php?lang={turkish or english}` After language is set, I plan to manage everything with only index2.php page.
my **index.php** code:

```
<a href="türkçe/" alt="Türkçe" title="Türkçe">Türkçe</a><br /><br />
<a href="english/" alt="English" title="English">English</a>
```

my **index2.php trial version** by the time being

```
echo $_GET[rd_dil];
if ($_GET[rd_dil] =='türkçe') {echo 'success';}
```

and my **.htaccess** is

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^türkçe(.+)$ index2.php?rd_dil=türkçe [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^english(.+)$ index2.php?rd_dil=english [L,QSA]
```

**My QUESTIONS:**

**question 1**
my index2.php output comes with 2 notices (below), what should I do for a notice safe design?

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant rd_dil - assumed 'rd_dil' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\index2.php on line 17
türkçe
Notice: Use of undefined constant rd_dil - assumed 'rd_dil' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\index2.php on line 18
success
```

**question 2**
Do you think that my plan, way of thinking is logical? If you have much more effective way in your mind can you please guide me? As I wrote, everything starts with language selection of viewer.

Comment: question 1 solved with the answer by Bhavik Shah. So only question 2 remains. BR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $_GET[rd_dil];
```

to

```
echo $_GET['rd_dil'];
```

will solve problem 1. You are missing quotes around the variable name. Thats the reason of notices.

For question 2, I would say that it really depends on the application. No plan is 100% efficient for all applications.